# Laravel 4 Error while executing composer install

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

When I try to run `composer install` I obtain the following error, 
Everything is fine if I run `composer update`, any idea? thanks

```
:# composer.phar install --no-scripts
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev].
    - laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev requires jeremeamia/superclosure 1.0.* -> satisfiable by jeremeamia/SuperClosure[1.0.1].
    - jeremeamia/SuperClosure 1.0.1 requires nikic/php-parser ~0.9 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[0.9.x-dev].
    - jeremeamia/SuperClosure 1.0.1 requires nikic/php-parser ~0.9 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[0.9.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: nikic/php-parser[1.0.x-dev, 0.9.x-dev].
    - Installation request for nikic/php-parser 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[1.0.x-dev].
```

Comment: Are you trying to install a fresh instance of composer or are you just updating your current packages? Because I don't see why you need to worry about composer install when you have update readily available to you? I would love to help, could you elaborate further?

Comment: thanks @KLVTZ, I'm currently in staging phase so I'd like to ensure that my testing server has exactly the same dependencies as the last time I run `update` in my development machine..

Comment: Ah! I understand now. So are you able to update in your dev environment, but your staging environment is not updating or pulling the latest dependencies? Have you tried doing a quick check to make sure the same behavior is not happening in your dev environment? If it is, it could be an issue with composer and packagist request.

Comment: My staging environment is indeed working with `composer update` but it is not with `composer install`.. seems like an `install` issue

Comment: Instead of `laravel/framework`, try `laravel/laravel`.

Comment: Joaquin, did you ever find a solution. I'm seeing the same issue. Specifically the following line.
- Can only install one of: nikic/php-parser[1.0.x-dev, 0.9.x-dev].

Comment: @CollinJames using 'laravel/laravel' seemed to work, no clue if it's a general solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)