# How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?

Tags: composer-php

I have installed one package via Composer and it installed Guzzlehttp too, because of the package.
After that I tried to install another package via Composer, which requires Guzzlehttp too and Composer, tried to install it again.

But I get that error :

> Problem 1
>
> - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0, 6.0.2].
> - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.2, 6.2.0].
> - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.2, 6.2.0].

I see what is the problem, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Its a dependency conflict. Please post your `require` section, so that other can take a look and suggest some better matching version constraints.

Comment: @JensA.Koch I would argue this is bad advice, because while that might solve the poster's question, other searchers who arrive at this page will not have a method for resolving this problem for themselves, other than posting their own `require` on the internet. In other words, it's not a general solution.

Answer (score 38):

The "*Can only install one [x, y]*" message appears when two different packages point to the same dependency, but different major, mutually exclusive versions where only one can be installed.

---

#### Troubleshooting

For example, one version can be "*locked at*" due to the information present in your `composer.lock` file which may conflict with what you're trying to install. In this case, when the confusion error comes with "*locked at x.y.z*" message, you may use the following commands to understand the existing dependencies of installed packages:

```
composer show -t
```

<sup>Note: `-t` shows as a nested tree view, drop it to see the flat list.</sup>

To see where the problematic package is referenced from in your project, run:

```
composer why org/package -t
```

<sup>Note: `-t` shows as a nested tree view, drop it to see the flat list.</sup>

To see the details of the package which you're trying to install, you may run:

```
composer show -a org/package # Package to inspect.
```

<sup>Note: To inspect the specific version, add `x.y.z`, e.g.: `composer show -a guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.0`</sup>

---

To further troubleshoot the problem, depending on your situation, you can try to:

- Update the existing packages with dependencies via:

  ```
  composer update --with-dependencies
  ```
- Upgrade or remove conflicting dependencies from your `composer.json` (keep it simple).
- When the confusion message shows "*locked at x.y.z*", use `composer why org/package` to see where the package is referenced (or check the content of `composer.lock` manually by looking for `x.y.z`). If won't help, consider removing `composer.lock` and re-try again;
- When asked to use [`composer.json` from the different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48429060/55075), select `n`.
- Re-try your plain `composer.json`, simplified configuration on the empty folder.
- Run `composer diagnose` to check for any common error.
- Use `-v`/`-vv`/`-vvv` to increase the verbosity of your commands.
- See also: [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48073506/55075)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and I just had to run

`composer update`

before installing the new package. This will work depending on whether the other installed packages have updated their dependencies too though.

Comment: Take note that this updates all dependencies in your composer.json file, which can introduce breaking changes if the dependencies are not pinned correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding a '^' before the version number. For example

`composer require drupal/slack:^1.2.0`

instead of

```
composer require drupal/slack:1.2.0
```

when the latter caused this error.