# Composer dependencies issue (friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle / doctrine/inflector)

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, composer-php

I am trying to resolve the following composer dependency issue, I usually understand and fix them but this time, I am having trouble.

Here it is:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/www/producteev4$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle dev-master requires doctrine/inflector 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev].
    - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle dev-master requires doctrine/inflector 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector 1.1.x-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev].
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[dev-master].
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you have `doctrine/inflector` included in your .json-file for composer, and it requests version 1.1.x-dev, but this symfony-package requires version 1.0.* .. in this case composer decides to install latest version... will this bundle work? idk

Comment: Could you show us your `composer.json`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)