# Guzzle 6 conflict with latest google php api client

Tags: php, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I've got some issue when trying to install google php api client into my existing php application using composer. I use the following command to install:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
```

The error that I got:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC2 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC8 requires google/auth 0.8 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.8].
    - Conclusion: don't install google/auth v0.8
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/psr7 (locked at 1.3.0) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.3.0].
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC6 requires google/auth 0.7 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.7].
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC7 requires google/auth 0.7 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install google/auth v0.7
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC4 requires google/auth 0.5 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.5].
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0-RC5 requires google/auth 0.5 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install google/auth v0.5
    - Installation request for google/apiclient ^2.0.0@RC -> satisfiable by google/apiclient[v2.0.0-RC1, v2.0.0-RC2, v2.0.0-RC3, v2.0.0-RC4, v2.0.0-RC5, v2.0.0-RC6, v2.0.0-RC7, v2.0.0-RC8].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

From google php api client requirements it says that it supports guzzle 6. Any ideas what might be the issue?

---

I tried to install `google/auth` `0.8` which is the latest, but got similar issues:

```
- Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3.0
- Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3.0
- google/auth v0.8 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.3.0].
- Installation request for guzzlehttp/psr7 (locked at 1.3.0) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.3.0]
```

Comment: It's not saying that `guzzlehttp/guzzle` is the issue, it's saying that those three particular versions are not considered because they do not support your version of it.  The conclusions are where the issues lie.  It appears to be a problem with `google/auth`.  Do you have a version of it installed already?

Comment: No I don't have google/auth install yet. I tried to install google/auth 0.8 which is the latest but got similar issues:
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3.0
    - google/auth v0.8 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.3.0].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/psr7 (locked at 1.3.0) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.3.0]

Comment: I think, I know what's the problem, google/auth only support guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.* so that means I need to either downgrade my guzzle or for google/auth and upgrade them to guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)