# composer error: Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I try install https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client for my php project via composer.

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "Intervention/image": "~2.3.7",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2" 
    }
}
```

I run this command:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

And result:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0 requires google/auth 0.8 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.8].
    - Installation request for google/apiclient 2.0 -> satisfiable by google/apiclient[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3.0
    - google/auth v0.8 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.1, 1.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.2, 1.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.3, 1.3.0].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/psr7 (locked at 1.3.0) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.3.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Also I installed `php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle` before...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing your project's requirement of `guzzlehttp/guzzle` and let your Google dependency tell composer what version it wants to pull in.  Google's package (for some reason) has a version floor of 1.2 for `guzzlehttp/psr7`, and composer is complaining that it can't figure out how to satisfy this requirement.

Since your new dependency (the Google package) also requires `guzzlehttp/guzzle`, you don't need to specifically require it, so I would just remove it and try `composer update` again.