# Composer: Your requirements could not be resolved while installing Laravel Tracker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to install this https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker package on my Laravel 5.2 using command:

```
composer require pragmarx/tracker
```

But then I get this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Using version ^2.0 for pragmarx/tracker
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for pragmarx/tracker ^2.0 -> satisfiable by pragmarx/tracker[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove ramsey/uuid 3.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid 3.4.1
    - pragmarx/tracker v2.0.0 requires ramsey/uuid ~2.8 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0].
    - Can only install one of: ramsey/uuid[2.8.0, 3.4.1].
    - Can only install one of: ramsey/uuid[2.8.1, 3.4.1].
    - Can only install one of: ramsey/uuid[2.8.2, 3.4.1].
    - Can only install one of: ramsey/uuid[2.8.3, 3.4.1].
    - Can only install one of: ramsey/uuid[2.8.4, 3.4.1].
    - Can only install one of: ramsey/uuid[2.9.0, 3.4.1].
    - Installation request for ramsey/uuid (locked at 3.4.1) -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[3.4.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I don't want to break my application. What should I do?

Comment: the problem is that your package hasn't been updated for laravel 5.2. try installing it on a laravel 5.0 project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Answer (score 1):

The new package depends on ramsey/uuid, that line also tells you which versions have been found to satisfy this requirement:

```
pragmarx/tracker v2.0.0 requires ramsey/uuid ~2.8 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0].
```

It seems that this package is already installed in a newer version, because these lines appears as well:

```
- Conclusion: remove ramsey/uuid 3.4.1
- Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid 3.4.1
```

Composer sums this up as following:

```
- Can only install one of: ramsey/uuid[2.8.0, 3.4.1].
```

Composer cannot install your new package because you have installed ramsey/uuid in a newer version that is incompatible to the required version.

You can try and send a pull request to the maintainer of pragmarx/tracker with the update of ramsey/uuid. Or you can search for a different package that is compatible with your installed packages.