# Google api library install error, due to guzzle has been installed previous

Tags: php, composer-php, google-api-client

I get the following error when I install `google-api-client`, previously I was installed `guzzle6` due to project need. Now I'm trying to merge two project in one.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for google/apiclient 2.0 -> satisfiable by google/apiclient[v2.0.0].
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0 requires google/auth 0.8 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.8].
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/psr7 1.3.1
    - google/auth v0.8 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.3.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.1, 1.3.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.2, 1.3.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.3, 1.3.1].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/psr7 (locked at 1.3.1) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.3.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run:

```
composer require google/apiclient:2.1.2
```

instead of `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0`.