# Composer/Packagist/Github: how to tell which version is stable?

Tags: php, github, composer-php, packagist

I'm getting a version conflict for the required package `phpmd/phpmd`, and I'm not sure why a common version can't be resolved.

Running  `composer require yvoronoy/magento2-bash-completion` yields...

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for yvoronoy/magento2-bash-completion ^1.0@beta -> satisfiable by yvoronoy/magento2-bash-completion[1.0.0-beta].
    - Conclusion: remove phpmd/phpmd 2.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install phpmd/phpmd 2.4.3
    - yvoronoy/magento2-bash-completion 1.0.0-beta requires phpmd/phpmd 2.3.* -> satisfiable by phpmd/phpmd[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: phpmd/phpmd[2.3.0, 2.4.3].
    - Can only install one of: phpmd/phpmd[2.3.1, 2.4.3].
    - Can only install one of: phpmd/phpmd[2.3.2, 2.4.3].
    - Can only install one of: phpmd/phpmd[2.3.3, 2.4.3].
    - Installation request for phpmd/phpmd (locked at 2.4.3, required as @stable) -> satisfiable by phpmd/phpmd[2.4.3].
```

My main app's `composer.json` has the following.

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "require-dev": {
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    }   
}
```

`yvoronoy/magento2-bash-completion` has its own `composer.json`, which include the following.

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "stable",  
    "require": {
        "phpmd/phpmd": "2.3.*",
    }
}
```

Looking at the Github page (https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd), shouldn't the version for `phpmd/phpmd` resolve to `2.3.3` by these `composer.json`s because that version is tagged (i.e. stable) in github?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble installing Magento, so I'm unable to work along and reproduce the issue; out of curiousity, can you change your entry for phpmd to `^2.3@stable`? Without the version number, it might be "locked" to the latest major.minor.

Comment: I'll fix that, just have created an issue on github https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento2-bash-completion/issues/5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)