# Unable to install sami on laravel 5.2.3 for api documentation

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I am trying to write documentation for a laravel 5.2.3 project and I intend to use Sami to acheive this.

I followed the the git hub link https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Sami and I tried to install using composer

composer require sami/sami

But I keep getting the error,

Using version ^3.3 for sami/sami
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for sami/sami ^3.3 -> satisfiable by sami/sami[v3.3.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.5
    - sami/sami v3.3.0 requires symfony/console ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.11, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.12, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.13, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.14, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.15, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.16, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.17, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.18, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.19, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.20, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.21, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.22, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.23, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.24, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.25, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.26, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.27, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.28, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.29, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.30, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.31, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.32, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.33, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.34, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.35, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.36, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.37, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.38, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.39, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.40, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.41, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.42, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.1, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.11, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.12, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.1, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.11, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.12, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.13, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.1, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.11, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.12, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.13, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.14, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.15, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.16, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.17, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.18, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.19, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.1, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.11, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.12, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.1, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.11, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.12, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.13, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.1, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.10, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.11, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.1, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.2, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.3, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.4, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.5, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.6, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.7, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.8, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.9, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.0, v3.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.1, v3.1.5].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v3.1.5) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.1.5].

Is Sami not compatible with Laravel 5.2.3? Because I also tried adding a lower sympony version(~2.6) but an error was displayed indicating the minimum sympony version for laravel 5.2.3 is 3.1.5.

What should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the latest official release v3.3 doesnt support symfony3 components which are used by laravel 5.3.
You can try to install the dev-master branch which supports symfony3.

```
composer require sami/sami dev-master
```

The dev-master branch is under development so it might have some hickups but i would bet it should work.

You could also ask for a release in the repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This removed the symphony issue but now i am faced with another dependency issue.

Comment: what dependency issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This removed the symphony issue but now i am faced with another dependency issue. It complains about nikic/php-parser and phpdocumentor/reflection. Sami needs nikic/php-parser to be at v3.* while phpdocumentor/reflection requires nikic/php-parser to be at v1.4.1..

Comment: im not sure where phpdocumentor/reflection is needed? but can this be removed?

Comment: I don't think it can be removed. But it is a requirement from sami according to their github repo.. https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Sami/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: sami requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock which does not require nikic/php-parser when i see correct.