# Magento 2 composer not working

Tags: magento, composer-php

I am trying install a lenguage package in Magento 2. I run composer `require eusonlito/magento2-language-es_es`, but composer show me a problem:

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^0.0.5 for eusonlito/magento2-language-es_es
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for eusonlito/magento2-language-es_es ^0.0.5 -> satisfiable by eusonlito/magento2-language-es_es[0.0.5].
    - Conclusion: remove magento/framework 100.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 100.1.2
    - eusonlito/magento2-language-es_es 0.0.5 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.10].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.11].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.12].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.13].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.6].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.9].
    - Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 100.1.2) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How I can solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

Installation of `eusonlito/magento2-language-es_es` create version problems (with `magento/framework` in this case). Here, your `magento/framework` version is too high for `magento2-language-es_es`. Try to see which dependencies `magento2-language-es_es` needs and change the version tag.