# Installing Laravel Dusk on 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-dusk

We've got a project running on laravel 5.3 - we're going to be updating it to 5.4 once the vendor packages are all updated.

However we're currently getting the following when running `composer require laravel/dusk` and wondering if there is anybody who knows a way around this?

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/dusk v1.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/dusk v1.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/dusk v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/dusk v1.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/dusk v1.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.1.10
    - Installation request for laravel/dusk ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/dusk[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v1.0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.10
    - laravel/dusk v1.0.0 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.1, v3.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.2, v3.1.10].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v3.1.10) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.1.10].
```

Comment: Laravel Dusk relies on a number of different packages which are all included with Laravel 5.4. I recommend upgrading your project to 5.4, then installing Dusk.

Comment: Just said can't upgrade yet  And as far as packages go, it says it needs minimal change so, main difference being the symfony console package, which is the only one complaining about. I'm sure there's some way, no matter how convoluted! Unless you have a link or something that proves it's not possible?

Comment: Hi, did you fine a solution for this?

Comment: We eventually upgraded to 5.4 and it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Answer (score 1):

`Laravel Dusk` is a new tool that will be introduced in `Laravel 5.4`.

Its not supported by the `Laravel 5.4 below version` due to some package dependencies.

So you need to upgrade into 5.4 to take the advantages of the `Laravel Dusk`

upgrade doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0)