# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages - Google Cloud

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've been searching a lot on the internet lately, but somehow I don't know how to correct this error on composer, I tried everything people said on stackoverflow . 
It happens when I try to **require google/cloud** or even when **I update composer**. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
composer require google/cloud
Using version ^0.28.0 for google/cloud
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.4.0 requires zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.5.0 requires zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.6.0 requires zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.6.1 requires zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.7.0 requires zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.1 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.0 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.1.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.1
    - Installation request for nikic/php-parser (locked at v3.0.5) -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v3.0.5].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.2.7
    - Installation request for erusev/parsedown (locked at 1.6.2) -> satisfiable by erusev/parsedown[1.6.2].
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor 2.* -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v2.5.0, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.9.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.2.7
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.0 requires cilex/cilex ~1.0 -> satisfiable by cilex/cilex[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0].
    - cilex/cilex 1.0.0 requires cilex/console-service-provider 1.*@dev -> satisfiable by cilex/console-service-provider[1.0.0, 1.1.0].
    - cilex/cilex 1.0.1 requires cilex/console-service-provider 1.* -> satisfiable by cilex/console-service-provider[1.0.0, 1.1.0].
    - cilex/cilex 1.1.0 requires cilex/console-service-provider 1.* -> satisfiable by cilex/console-service-provider[1.0.0, 1.1.0].
    - cilex/console-service-provider 1.0.0 requires symfony/console ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - cilex/console-service-provider 1.1.0 requires symfony/console ~2.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.11, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.12, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.13, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.14, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.15, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.16, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.17, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.18, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.19, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.20, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.21, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.22, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.23, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.24, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.25, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.26, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.27, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.28, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.29, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.30, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.31, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.32, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.33, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.34, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.35, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.36, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.37, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.38, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.39, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.40, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.41, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.42, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.1, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.11, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.12, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.1, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.11, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.12, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.13, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.1, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.11, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.12, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.13, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.14, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.15, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.16, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.17, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.18, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.19, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.20, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.21, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.22, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.23, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.24, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.25, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.26, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.27, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.1, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.11, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.12, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.13, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.14, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.15, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.16, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.17, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.18, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.19, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.20, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.1, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.11, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.12, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.13, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.1.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.1, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.10, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.11, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.2.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.1, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.2, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.3, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.4, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.5, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.6, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.7, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.8, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.9, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.0, v3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.1, v3.2.7].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v3.2.7) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.7].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

and here is my JSON.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes": "1.0.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: `zend-i18n 2.1.6 requires ext-intl` I think is key here. Check http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

Comment: you dont have zend framework installed. install it first then try google cloud. it will solve your prblem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install php-intl` should solve your problem.