# Can't install Google Cloud PHP client

Tags: php, composer-php, google-cloud-storage

Having issues installing [Google Cloud PHP client](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php) using Composer.

Any ideas how to best resolve the issues:

```
Using version ^0.33.1 for google/cloud                               
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                             Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: google/auth[v1.0, v0.11.1].
    - Can only install one of: google/auth[v1.0, v0.11.1].
    - Can only install one of: google/auth[v1.0, v0.11.1].
    - google/cloud v0.33.1 requires google/auth ^1.0 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v1.0].
    - Installation request for google/cloud ^0.33.1 -> satisfiable by google/cloud[v0.33.1].
    - Installation request for google/auth (locked at v0.11.1) -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.11.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
sfbstack@villada:~/api/dev$
```

Comment: Does this happen when you run `composer require google/cloud` in an empty directory? I just tried it and it works fine...

Comment: @JiriHrazdil. hmm... you are right.  After a little more testing I found some old google dependencies in the project that must have been installed previously. After removing them, everything works.  I have voted up your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)