# Conflict 2 packages composer update

Tags: php, composer-php

These two packages conflict when try install or update with composer

```
"cagartner/correios-consulta": "^0.1.7"
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0"
```

result

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.8.0].
- Installation request for cagartner/correios-consulta ^0.1.7 -> satisfiable by cagartner/correios-consulta[0.1.7].
- dompdf/dompdf v0.8.0 requires phenx/php-svg-lib 0.2.* -> satisfiable by phenx/php-svg-lib[v0.2].
- cagartner/correios-consulta 0.1.7 requires cagartner/phpquery 0.9.8 -> satisfiable by cagartner/phpquery[0.9.8].
- barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0].
- cagartner/phpquery 0.9.8 requires sabberworm/php-css-parser 5.1.* -> satisfiable by sabberworm/php-css-parser[5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2].
- Can only install one of: sabberworm/php-css-parser[6.0.0, 5.1.0].
- Can only install one of: sabberworm/php-css-parser[6.0.0, 5.1.1].
- Can only install one of: sabberworm/php-css-parser[6.0.0, 5.1.2].
- phenx/php-svg-lib v0.2 requires sabberworm/php-css-parser 6.0.* -> satisfiable by sabberworm/php-css-parser[6.0.0, 6.0.1].
- Conclusion: don't install sabberworm/php-css-parser 6.0.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)