# Installation failed for laravel/lumen-installer: guzzlehttp/guzzle locked at 6.3.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I'm trying to install Lumen through the command `composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"` but throws the following error on terminal.

```
Changed current directory to /home/lykos/.config/composer
Using version ^1.0 for laravel/lumen-installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.1
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v4.0.3) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.0.3].
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.3.0
    - Installation request for laravel/lumen-installer ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/lumen-installer[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.3.0
    - laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0|~5.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.1, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.2, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.0, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.1, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.2, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.3, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.4, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.5, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.6, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.7, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.1.8, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.0, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.1, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.2, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.3, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.4, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.1, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.2, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.3, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.1.0, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.2.0, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.0, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 6.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.2, 6.3.0].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.3.0) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

From a google search I tried to do this `rm -R ~/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp`

but throws an error as there's no such a directory

> `rm: cannot remove '/home/lykos/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp': No such
>   file or directory`

My `~/.config/composer/composer.json` file looks like this

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^1.5"
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: You can't delete the `~/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp` because it didn't install.

Can you show us your composer.json?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Try running this: `composer global require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Comment: @Jeff Mattson updated my main post

Comment: The last line you gave me `Using version ^6.3 for guzzlehttp/guzzle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
`

Comment: Try deleting the whole `vendor` folder and running composer install again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taylor fixed this in v1.0.3, but it hasn't been tagged, so you can install dev-master to get the updated version:
`composer global require laravel/lumen-installer:dev-master`

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove global `~/.composer` directory. Install `lumen/installer` first, then `laravel/installer` global. Works for me fine.

Answer (score 1):

> laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.0 requires `guzzlehttp/guzzle` `~4.0|~5.0`
>
> Installation request for `guzzlehttp/guzzle` (locked at `6.3.0`)

This means `guzzlehttp/guzzle` is locked at `6.3.0`" as per your `composer.lock` file, and your package (`laravel/lumen-installer`) requires `guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0|~5.0`. Check it by `grep 6.3.0 ~/.composer/composer.lock`  command.

Therefore you need to remove `guzzlehttp/guzzle` from your `~/.composer/composer.json` as per the suggestion:

> Conclusion: remove `guzzlehttp/guzzle` `6.3.0`

Otherwise, if it's not there, you need to remove the package which depends on it, or upgrade `laravel/lumen-installer` to v1.0.3 (as already suggested). E.g.

```
composer global require laravel/lumen-installer:^1.0.3
```

To see the dependency tree (what is using different version of `guzzle`), you can run:

```
composer global show -t
```

See also: [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36611550/55075)

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the cache with `composer clearcache` then run

```
composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"
```

It is mostly caused when composer cached some of the packages and try to install required packages from cache.

try installing with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen project`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Lykos try to install with composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem today, it was caused by some other globally required packages, please check `~/.composer/composer.json`. In my case, `laravel/install` 2.0.1 wants `guzzle` 6.0.0 while an old `lumen/install` wants `guzzle` 5.3.2, but Composer can allow only one version installed. Problem solved by removing the lumen line and run composer update in that directory.