# How to initialise a Symfony Console project using Composer in a way that constrains it to stick to the Long Term Release version?

Tags: php, symfony, console, composer-php

My goal is to run a Composer's `require` command to initialise a Symfony Console project.

When running composer's `require` command, I believe it is possible to restrict the required package to specific a version.

I am considering using this to stick to the Long Term Release version of Symfony which will be supported for longer.

According to the [Symfony Release Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#long-term-support-versions) the current LTS version is `3.4`.

According to [Composer's `require` command documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) and [Composer's version constraints documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-), the package and version can be specified as: `symfony/console:~3.4`.

However, when I run the `composer` command to install symfony/console 3.4 in an empty directory I get the following errors. (I have PHP and Composer is installed on my MacOS High Sierra):

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ composer self-update
You are already using composer version 1.6.2 (stable channel).
Johns-MBP:foo jw$ php --version
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

I have created a new directory, changed into it, ensured composer is updated to the latest version and ensured PHP is 7.*.

```
$ composer require symfony/console:~3.4
No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at /Users/me/Documents/Projects/FilterProject/filter-environment? [Y,n]? Y
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.1
    - symfony/process v2.6.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v3.4.0].
    - symfony/console v3.4.0 conflicts with symfony/process[v2.6.4].
    - Installation request for symfony/console ~3.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3].
    - Installation request for symfony/process (locked at v2.6.4, required as ~2.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v2.6.4].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I am quite new to Symfony and so may be misunderstanding the connection between the version number used for Symfony core versus the version number used by Symfony/console.

Which composer command does one run to `require` the LTS version of Symfony Console in fresh project?

Comment: Make sure composer is up to date with composer self-update.  Current version is 1.6.2.  Make sure you have at least php 5.6 installed.  I just tried your command and it worked as expected.  It did not complain about a missing composer.json file.  It just created one.

Comment: Thanks Cerad, the fact the you said it had worked for you gave me hope.

I have got it working now. I will write an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work, thanks to @Cerad's comment.

First, I ensured that I have the latest version of composer and PHP 7.

Then I re-ran the command and spotted the problem:

I was installing this application in a sub-folder of a Homestead Improved project and composer was interactively asking me to use its `composer.json` file!

I was being sloppy and did not read the interactive question fully. I assumed it was asking me to create a new `composer.json` file. But instead it was asking if I wanted to ammend the composer.json file of the parent project above.

```
$ composer require symfony/console:~3.4
No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use
the one at /Users/me/Documents/Projects/FilterProject/filter-environment? [Y,n]? Y
```

If I answered `Y` then my choice conflicts with some dependencies in the parent project.

By choosing the correct answer of `n` I did not have a problem and it worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

> Installation request for symfony/process (locked at v2.6.4).

This message means that your `symfony/process` is locked at v2.6.4 (in your `composer.lock`). Which is confusing, since *Composer* reported *No `composer.json` in current directory*.

Since you've chosen `Y` to load `composer.json` from another folder (probably from the different non-related project), so next time try to not select it (by choosing `n`). So you can install it on the empty folder. If you mean to install it globally, run: `composer global require symfony/console`.

---

When you're working with the existing `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, try to update your dependencies by:

```
composer update --with-dependencies
```

Otherwise, consider removing `composer.lock` and installing from scratch by `composer install`.

Comment: Thanks @kenorb I worked out the problem. The problem was identified by the first notice `No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at /Users/me/Documents/Projects/FilterProject/filter-environment? [Y,n]? Y`. Basically I was mistakenly trying to initialise composer in a sub-directory of another composer project.