# With composer, how to force the version of a package required from another one?

Tags: composer-php

I would like to install a package ("Package 1") using composer.
But there is an *incompatible version conflict* : one of its dependencies ("Package 2") is incompatible with one of another package.

**How could I force the installation of a package who requires an incompatible package version** ("Package 2")**?**

Or **How could I signify that the package 2 could have another version ?**

This is the input and the output :

```
 php composer require company1/package-name
```

.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: company2/package-name2[v5.8.0, v2.3.0].
```

Note : obviously, using a newer version of a package required by another one could cause some sort of *instability/php problems* in the overall website, but this is not an issue here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)