# Composer Google API Download Failed

Tags: google-api, composer-php

I tried to download google api using composer to a legacy code but, the following error appeared:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for google/apiclient 2.0 -> satisfiable by google/apiclient[v2.0.0].
    - google/apiclient v2.0.0 requires google/auth 0.8 -> satisfiable by google/auth[v0.8].
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/psr7 1.4.2
    - google/auth v0.8 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.* -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.0, 1.4.2].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.1, 1.4.2].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.2, 1.4.2].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.2.3, 1.4.2].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/psr7 (locked at 1.4.2) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.4.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you share the existing `composer.json`?

Comment: Requiring `google/apiclient:^2.0` resolves to v2.2.1 for me, so there must be some caveat in the existing file...

Answer (score 1):

Try removing vendor/google and then run `composer install` again, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Can only install one of: `guzzlehttp/psr7`[`1.2.3`, `1.4.2`].

Your dependencies led to confusion of two different major versions of the package, but only one can be installed.

The `locked at 1.4.2` message means this package has been already installed as per your `composer.lock` file, and you're trying to install different version not compatible with your existing criteria.

```
$ composer show -a google/auth | grep psr7
guzzlehttp/psr7 ~1.2
```

You can check which existing package depends on the locked version by checking the dependency tree:

```
composer show -t
```

In some cases, removing `composer.lock` may help.

Otherwise, to see why (from where) the package is referenced, run:

```
composer why guzzlehttp/psr7 -t
```

See also: [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36611550/55075)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for me, it works just removing `composer.lock`!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked this:

1. remove vendor/google folder in composer
2. clean up cache for composer "composer clear-cache"
3. increase timeout for install "composer config process-timeout 3600"
4. "composer install"

After you can decrease timeout back to 600.