# I can't upgrade PHPUnit 5 with composer using PHP 5.6 on WAMP

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, wamp

I had PHPUnit v4.7 and I tried to go to v5. So why is code-coverage not installed and how do I fix it? I already tried removing the phpunit folder altogether. I am using the install command as in https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-5.html

This is my output:

```
c:\[path to]\composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^5
./composer.json has been updated
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install phpunit/php-code-coverage 2.2.4
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.0.0 requires phpunit/php-code-coverage ~3.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/php-code-coverage[3.0.0, 2.2.4].
   ... <repeated with more versions>
    - Can only install one of: phpunit/php-code-coverage[3.3.3, 2.2.4].
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage (locked at 2.2.4) -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[2.2.4].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

update: this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
        "adamwathan/bootforms": "@dev",
        "patricktalmadge/bootstrapper": "~5",
        "frozennode/administrator": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5",
        "laracasts/integrated": "^0.15.6"        
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: you tried to look at your `composer.json`?

Comment: @AlexKarshin yes, I don't know what's missing, see https://pastebin.com/un9Hpan8

Comment: How about just adding `phpunit/php-code-coverage` with required version to your `composer.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `phpunit/php-code-coverage` is already locked at `2.2.4` (check the `composer.lock` which requires `phpunit/phpunit` `~4` (see: `composer show -a phpunit/php-code-coverage 2.2.4`), and you're trying to install `phpunit/phpunit` `5`.

Now, `phpunit/phpunit` `5.0.0` requires `phpunit/php-code-coverage ~3.0`:

```
$ composer show -a phpunit/phpunit 5.0.0 | grep coverage
phpunit/php-code-coverage ~3.0
```

where your locked version is `2.2.4`, and you cannot have both (`3.3.3`, `2.2.4`).

To see why the specific package is locked, run:

```
composer why -t phpunit/php-code-coverage
```

<sup>Note: You may also add a version/constraint at the end.</sup>

So you can try to:

- Update your existing packages along with all dependencies by:

  ```
  composer update --with-dependencies
  ```
- Update specific package which is failing by:

  ```
  composer update phpunit/php-code-coverage --with-dependencies
  ```
- Remove `composer.lock` and reinstall all your packages again by:

  ```
  composer install
  ```

To see the current tree of dependencies, run:

```
composer show -t
```

See also:

- [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36611550/55075)
- [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48073506/55075)

Comment: I already got it to work, using 
    `"phpunit/phpunit": "5.0.*",`
    `"phpunit/php-code-coverage": "~3.0",`
    `"phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "~3.0"`