# Problem of Laravel Framework version for using the package mailjet/laravel-mailjet

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mailjet

I've a problem for using mailjet/laravel-mailjet, it seems a problem of versions.
I was using Laravel Framework 5.6.33 and i got

```
Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.6.39, 5.4.x-dev].
```

i've change my composer.json and now, i'm using Laravel Framework 5.6.39 but i've still the same problem

```
 $ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.6.39
```

There is the answer when i try to install mailjet/laravel-mailjet

```
$ composer require mailjet/laravel-mailjet
Using version ^1.1 for mailjet/laravel-mailjet
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.6.39, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, v5.6.39].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, v5.6.39].
    - mailjet/laravel-mailjet 1.1.0 requires laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev].
    - Installation request for mailjet/laravel-mailjet ^1.1 -> satisfiable by mailjet/laravel-mailjet[1.1.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.39 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.39].
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a "Can only install one of:" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611550/how-to-resolve-a-can-only-install-one-of-conflict)

Comment: That package looks like it hasn't been maintained in over a year. There's even an outstanding pull request to fix this specific dependency conflict that hasn't been accepted in months. You may want to look for another package instead, or use your own wrapper for their library: https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php

Comment: did you fix your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

the 4th line explains it all.

`mailjet/laravel-mailjet 1.1.0 requires laravel/framework 5.4.*`

so, you can't use `v5.6.39`, only `5.4.*`